# Spark Dataset unique id performance - row_number vs monotonically_increasing_id

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I want to assign a unique Id to my dataset rows. I know that there are two implementation options:

1. First option:

   ```
   import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window;
   ds.withColumn("id",row_number().over(Window.orderBy("a column")))
   ```
2. Second option:

   ```
   df.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
   ```

The second option is not sequential ID and it doesn't really matter.

I'm trying to figure out is if there are any performance issues of those implementation. That is, if one of this option is very slow compared to the other. Something more meaningful that: "monotonically_increasing_id is very fast over row_number because it's not sequential or ..."

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`monotically_increasing_id` is distributed which performs according to *partition* of the data.

whereas

`row_number()` using `Window` function without `partitionBy` (as in your case) is not distributed. When we don't define `partitionBy`, all the data are sent to one executor for generating row number.

Thus, **it is certain that `monotically_increasing_id()` will perform better than `row_number()` without `partitionBy` defined**.

Answer (score 12):

**TL;DR** It is not even a competition.

**Never** use:

```
row_number().over(Window.orderBy("a column"))
```

for anything else than summarizing results, that already fit in a single machine memory.

To apply window function without `PARTITION BY` Spark has to shuffle all data into a single partition. On any large dataset this will just crash the application. Sequential and not distributed won't even matter.

Comment: What shall I use? I need to order by certain cols, please help.